# SQL query for a single branch in parent-child table

Tags: mysql, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have a table that stores items (actually web pages) using the adjacency list model as it's not very deep. For example:

```
id    fragment     parent_id
1     home         -1
2      about-us     1
3       meet-us     2
4       contact-us  2
5        map        4
6       more        2
7      products     1
```

To extract the whole branch below about-us I have tried the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT t1.fragment, t2.fragment, t3.fragment
FROM pages t1
LEFT JOIN pages t2 on t2.parent_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN pages t3 on t3.parent_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id=2
```

But it doesn't produce the actual row with children (contact-us above), only:

```
meet-us
contact-us <-this row is missing
 map
more
```

It works fine on the whole tree (i.e. without the WHERE clause).

Any help much appreciated.